# How to mount a white board on a wall without making holes in the wall?

Tags: walls

I'm planning on buying a big white board to put on my bedroom wall. I don't want to commit to it though, so I don't want to nail it to the wall. Does anyone know of a non permanent solution to fix the board to the wall?

EDIT: Haven't bought the board yet, so I don't know the weight. Dimensions will probably be around 72" by 40"

Comment: How heavy is it? What are the dimensions?

Comment: Haven't bought it yet, so I don't know the weight.  Dimensions will probably be around 72" by 40"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. When you add information to your question, you should edit it right into the question rather than adding it in a comment; it makes it much easier for future readers to get all the information.

Comment: Is this going to be a typical framed whiteboard with marker tray?  Or are you going to buy a sheet of melamine?  If the latter, it will be cheaper and you have a whole lot more surface area to work with.  However, I can't think of anyway that you are gonna mount something that large reliably without a hole.  It doesn't have to be a large hole but it's gonna have to be a hole.

Answer (score 2):

Just get a whiteboard adhesive roll. You can make it the entire wall if you want. And you can easily remove it and reuse it in another location.

**adhesive whiteboard roll**

[image]

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007KT29I)

Comment: Just make sure to get the easily removable version - there are also ones with a more permanent adhesive, but this (generic type of product) was exactly what I thought of when I read the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of success with those "Command" adhesives from 3M, but it entirely depends on how heavy it is.  If you are not familiar with them they have a tab that allows them to break their glue bond by stretching the material and I have not had any leave marks on the wall.  They are available at about any hardware store.  They have a weight rating on the package and I would figure half that.

Answer (score 1):

You can hang whiteboard with industrial strength velcro. I buy the role at Home Depot that is rated to hold 10 lbs. Because it is attaching to the wall, there is not 10 lbs of weight actually on the velcro strips. I put them on every corner and one in the center top and bottom and  left and right. It hold great, we do this in our school for classrooms. It works perfectly. I buy the channel guides and put them around the whiteboard to protect the edges (the whiteboard at Home Depot and Lowes will bend easily at the corners and sides). Or you can trim them, like a frame. Works great, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Buy an easel and set it on that.
- Build an easel-like frame and set it on that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I really want it on the wall